# How can I set a TTL on a Parse Object Attribute

Tags: parse-platform, ttl

I saw this post https://www.parse.com/questions/ttl-support

However, after extensively searching I found no other conversations or posts regarding TTL like functionality in Parse.

Has anyone done something like that?

I am saving Firebase URI's in a Parse Object and after a set amount of time (TTL) I want those references removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to set up a job using Parse Cloud Code. This way requires the [Parse Command Line Tool](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code/windows). You can follow this quickstart for setting up everything.

For example, let's say you have an object like this in the 'Content' class:

```
{
    "belongsTo": {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "Test",
        "objectId": "98765"
    },
    "createdAt": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.004Z",
    "expiration": {
        "__type": "Date",
        "iso": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.004Z"
    },
    "isLive": true,
    "content": "This is a text",
    "objectId": "01234",
    "updatedAt": "2016-01-03T12:49:33.004Z"
}
```

You want to toggle the field "isLive" to false to essentially keep your query from returning old data. You could use something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.job('ExpirationCheck', function(request, status)  {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var d = new Date();
    var now = new Date(d.getTime()); 
    var query = new Parse.Query('Content');
    query.lessThanOrEqualTo('expiration', now );
    query.each(function(row) {
        row.set('isLive', false);
        return row.save()
    }).then(function() {
        status.success('Success');
    }, function(error) {
        status.error('Error');
    });
});
```

Then, in the 'Jobs' tab in Parse, you can set up a job that runs on an interval, referencing this new job of 'ExpirationCheck'.

Alternatively, if you wanted, you could delete the data outright, but I prefer having a toggle field.